# Javascript - Enviar parámetros en "eventlistener" dentro de un for

Tags: javascript, array, bucle-for, function

ante todo disculpas por la torpeza y los "alert" pero no consigo dar con el problema y creo que es algo que no logro comprender.

Es sencillo, tengo este código:

```
function mostrar(e){

alert(e);}


window.onload=function(){

listadoEdiciones();}

for(e=0;e<mtg.length;e++){
    document.getElementById(mtg[e][2]).addEventListener('click', function(){mostrar(e);});
}}
```

La idea es que cuando haga click en los elementos listados, mandar el número del parámetro "e" del "for" a una función pero salta el mítico "undefined" o en este caso el valor total del for, que es 21 siempre.

Dejo abajo el codigo entero para que lo veáis mejor todo en conjunto.

https://jsfiddle.net/Lf4z2bh3/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema esta en el uso de `var`. Al definir variables de tipo `var` se genera un asunto llamado **hoisting** lo cuál hace que siempre se apunte a la misma dirección de memoria para resolver una variable, en este caso tu iterador `e`. Como el último valor que obtiene esta variable debido al for es 21 este valor se va a compartir en todas los event listeners que creaste.

Una solución sencilla para esto es definir tu variable de iteración como `let` en vez de `var`, este tipo de definición no genera hoisting, por lo cuál siempre se va a preservar el valor y se producirá un *closure* que es básicamente una función que atrapa el estado de una variable en un momento dado.

En general te recomiendo dejar de usar `var` para definiciones de variables, en vez de eso utiliza siempre `const` y `let`, esto te facilitará la vida.

Ejemplo de lo que deberías cambiar:

```js
window.onload=function(){
    
    listadoEdiciones();
    
    for(let i = 0; i < mtg.length; i++) {
        //document.getElementById(mtg[e][2]).addEventListener('click', mostrar);
        document.getElementById(mtg[i][2]).addEventListener('click', function(){mostrar(i);});
    }
}
```

Finalmente tu **jsFiddle** quedaría así:  https://jsfiddle.net/njseqfyd/

Comment: Funciona perfecto pero solamente tengo un "var" en el código, ¿o es que al crear un for se crea un var automaticamente?

Muchas gracias

Comment: Realmente el `var` de tu for es el mismo, solo que lo estas reusando en varios lugares.